# How do I start using a .json file to read and write variables externally?

Tags: json, python-3.x

In this situation, I want these 4 variables to be saved in an external .json file. If they are not present in the .json file, then I want these questions to be asked. They are global variables.

```
monthlyWage = int(input("What is your monthly wage? "))
monthlySpendings = int(input("What are your monthly spendings? ")) 
monthlyOverdraft = int(input("What is your monthly overdraft? "))
monthlySavings = int(input("How much do you add into your savings account per month? "))
totalSpendings = int(monthlySpendings + monthlyOverdraft + monthlySavings)
```

Comment: what is the desired json schema? also what have you tried so far?

Comment: so far, i have tried nothing. I have never heard of a .json file, however, I was told that its the best way to do what I want

Comment: Split your problem up into multiple steps. First find a way of storing your variables as you receive the input. For example try storing the results in a [list](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp) or [dict](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp). Then you need to find a way of detecting missing inputs, for example the [None](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_none.asp) keyword can be used. And then try loading and saving using [json](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_none.asp)